# Qqlite: results in variables Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, dom-events

I'm trying to transfer the results of my query in Sqlite to variables of the Javascript, but it does not work!

My code is:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
var ide = 1;
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tab_users', [ide], function (tx, results) {
  var len = results.rows.length, i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var_name = results.rows.item(i).name;
    var_country = results.rows.item(i).country;
    
  }
});
});
alert ("Name is " + var_name + " and country is " + var_country);
```

This code only works if I put the ALERT inside the loop . This way:

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var_name = results.rows.item(i).name;
    var_country = results.rows.item(i).country;
    alert ("Name is " + var_name + " and country is " + var_country);
    
  }
```

But I need to use these variables in the rest of my code.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: This question not  been asked before: I'm not using jQuery

Comment: Put the rest of your code in/after the loop but before the end of the `executeSql` callback. Or use promises.

Comment: How to use promises ?